# CSS working on tablet, but not mobile phone after phonegap android build

Tags: android, jquery, css, cordova

The CSS of an app I wrapped with PhoneGap build is displaying correctly on a tablet, but not on a mobile phone. The icons, the JS, and most of the CSS works just fine. However the custom header color and panel CSS is not displaying correctly. The CSS seems to be referring back to jQuery Mobile CSS. How can I fix that?

Also, the href to the CSS comes after the href to jQuery.

Edit:

Here is my header information:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Mobile</title>
<meta name = "viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<!--<link href="Overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<!--<link href="mquery.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<!--<link href="css/phone.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/HomeScreenIcon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="img/SplashSceen.jpg"/>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.4.0/moment.min.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/categories.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>var __adobewebfontsappname__="dreamweaver"</script>
<script src="http://use.edgefonts.net/source-sans-pro:n6:default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oxygen:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="css/overwrite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: are you loading your application in android webview

Comment: What have you done so far? What is your code?

Comment: @VishalMokal- Yikes, I can't say I know what that is! I will read up on it now. Can yo utell me where I find this information?

Comment: @jsve- So far my application file containsjs, css, and img folders with a config.xml file and index.html file - nothing else.